# tiling images in a grid (i.e. with wrapround) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

The short version of what I'd like to do is take a stack of images in the format (h, w, num_images) and tile them in a grid to produce a single image that can be drawn easily, but I'd like to have them in a grid, i.e. with wrap around (and I'd like to do this in tensorflow, i.e. the graph outputs a grid image ready to draw).

by inputting either:

a.) number of columns (i.e. maximum number of images on a single row)

OR

b.) a maximum width (e.g. screen width). and it calculates the above automatically

I have numpy code which does it, but it's quite slow, it makes more sense to do it on the GPU as part of the graph I think.

my tensorflow graph code is this (t is the output of a convolution layer, so the last axis contains the stack of images):

```
act = tf.squeeze(t) # batch size is 1, so remove it
act = tf.unstack(act, num=num_filters, axis=-1) # split last axis (filters) into list of (h, w)
act = tf.stack(act) # re-stack on first axis
```

this gives me (num_filters, h, w) which I feed into a more generic numpy code I'd written which puts that in a grid (my numpy code is quite long, because it's more generic and works with variable size images, so I'm not including it below).

Is this possible to do directly in tensorflow?

(note, if I were to do tf.concat instead of tf.stack I can tile them side by side, but they don't have the wrap around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function has been added to TensorFlow that does exactly this: [tf.contrib.gan.eval.image_grid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/eval/image_grid). It accepts as arguments an input tensor of shape `[batch, width, height, channels]`, as well as the shape of the image grid, the dimensions of each image, and the number of image channels. It works very well and is easy to use.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! I was looking for something like this myself and stumbled upon it. It is definitely a helpful thing to have.

Comment: PS: This is not an option for folks on TF2

Answer (score 3):

For images with shape [Batch, Width, Height, Channels] this can be done in tensorflow using

```
def image_grid(x, size=6):
    t = tf.unstack(x[:size * size], num=size*size, axis=0)
    rows = [tf.concat(t[i*size:(i+1)*size], axis=0) 
            for i in range(size)]
    image = tf.concat(rows, axis=1)
    return image[None]
```

Comment: This answer is relevant (and very concise) for TF2.

Answer (score 0):

My numpy code does it in less than 20 lines and is pretty fast. It's pretty fast when I tile images of up 10000x10000x3. It fills up the last few tiles with zeros if there are insufficient images.

```py
def reshape_row(arr):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1), arr)

def reshape_col(arr):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: np.concatenate((x,y), axis=0), arr)

def arbitrary_rows_cols(arr, num_rows, num_cols, gray=False):
    num_images, height, width, depth, = arr.shape
    rows = []
    for i in range(num_rows):
        row_image = arr[i*num_cols:i*num_cols+num_cols]
        r_n, r_h, r_w, r_d = row_image.shape
        if row_image.shape[0] != num_cols:
            for _ in range(num_cols - row_image.shape[0]):
                row_image = np.concatenate((row_image, np.expand_dims(np.zeros((height, width, depth)), axis=0)), axis=0)
        row_image = reshape_row(row_image)
        rows.append(row_image)
    mosaic = reshape_col(rows)
    return mosaic
```

You could translate this code into TensorFlow code and it might be faster. Would be interesting to see a performance comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found quite a simple way of doing it by entering number of rows (which isn't ideal, but good enough for now).

```
def make_grid(t, num_images, num_rows=2):
    '''takes stack of images as (1, w, h, num_images) and tiles them into a grid'''
    t = tf.squeeze(t) # remove single batch, TODO make more flexible to work with higher batch size
    t = tf.unstack(t, num=num_images, axis=-1) # split last axis (num_images) into list of (h, w)
    t = tf.concat(t, axis=1) # tile all images horizontally into single row
    t = tf.split(t, num_rows, axis=1) # split into desired number of rows
    t = tf.concat(t, axis=0) # tile rows vertically
    return t
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that greates a square grid if you do not specify how many colums you want, and otherwise a grid with n_cols

```
def tf_batch_to_canvas(X, cols: int = None):
"""
reshape a batch of images into a grid canvas to form a single image.

Parameters
----------
X: Tensor
    Batch of images to format. [N, H, W, C]-shaped
cols: int
    how many columns the grid should have. If None, a square grid will be created.
Returns
-------
image_grid: Tensor
    Tensor representing the image grid. [1, HH, WW, C]-shaped

Raises
------
    ValueError: The input tensor must be 4 dimensional

Examples
--------

x = np.ones((9, 100, 100, 3))
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
canvas = batches.tf_batch_to_canvas(x)
assert canvas.shape == (1, 300, 300, 3)

canvas = batches.tf_batch_to_canvas(x, cols=5)
assert canvas.shape == (1, 200, 500, 3)
"""
if len(X.shape.as_list()) > 4:
    raise ValueError("input tensor has more than 4 dimensions.")
N, H, W, C = X.shape.as_list()
rc = math.sqrt(N)
if cols is None:
    rows = cols = math.ceil(rc)
else:
    cols = max(1, cols)
    rows = math.ceil(N / cols)
n_gray_tiles = cols * rows - N
if n_gray_tiles > 0:
    gray_tiles = tf.zeros((n_gray_tiles, H, W, C), X.dtype)
    X = tf.concat([X, gray_tiles], 0)
image_shape = (H, W)
n_channels = C
return image_grid(X, (rows, cols), image_shape, n_channels)
```

https://github.com/theRealSuperMario/edflow/blob/tf_batches/edflow/iterators/tf_batches.py#L8-L53

Basically, you can now use `tf.contrib.gan.eval.image_grid`, depending on your tensorflow version.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/eval/image_grid

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/eval/python/eval_utils_impl.py#L34-L80